# Laravel redirect not working in recursive function call

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having an issue in my LoginController (Laravel) where a redirect call does not work as expected, and instead produces a blank page.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...

            //  dd("test") here outputs "test" but the redirect doesn't work

            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        $this->doSomethingElse($request);
    }

    private function doSomethingElse(Request $request)
    {
        // do stuff...

        return $this->authenticate($request);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: use `return $this->doSomethingElse($request);`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a route named dashboard in  your web.php? like this

```
   Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
      return view('yourview');
   })->name('dashboard');
```

Hope this help you...